# Heroku - Build Error - Could not find Module Request

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

I have a file that works in local enviroment perfectly fine. But when i deploy it to Heroku it gets a build Error. The Heroku logs show me that it cannot find module request. I also took attention that the `package.json` is configured right:
Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "nodejs - express - server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "proxy-request.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node proxy-request.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "example",
    "heroku"
  ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "request": "^2.87.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.11.2"
  }
}
```

And these are the packages i use in my proxy-request.js file:

```
const request = require('request');
const http = require('http');
const url = require('url');
```

Answer (score 1):

When deploying Nodejs to Heroku, you create a file Procfile it run server file app.js, you can try the following after code

```js
//package.json
{
  "name": "nodejs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "ejs": "^2.5.7",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.33",
    "mongoose": "^4.12.4",
    "nodemon": "^1.12.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "pg": "^6.1.0",
    "request": "^2.83.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.2",
    "router": "^1.3.2"
  }
}
```

```html
//Procfile
web: node app.js

//app.js
var request = require("request");
```

Comment: I have a procfile already that looks as follows: `web: node proxy-request.js`

Comment: you now try create a new project, after then,you is install moduel request ,you after then deploying to heroku see, if no error, you see again,only way